# SPARK task-result-getter StackOverflow Error on Task Serialization

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, stack-overflow

some of the spark jobs are failing due StackOverflowError.

Here Trace:

```
ResultStage 363 (save at Transform.scala:156) failed in 17.392 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 363.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 363.0 (TID 974) (<executor_ip> executor 3): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:1094)
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:184)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ByteBufferInputStream.read(ByteBufferInputStream.scala:49)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2893)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2909)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:3430)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1862)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:527)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1046)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2357)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:527)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1046)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2357)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:527)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1046)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2357)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:527)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1046)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2357)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:527)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

and so..

This Trace is from a Thread : TaskResultGetter.
Thread stack size : 1mb.

How to resolve this stackOverflowError, is there are suggestion to avoid this Exception?

Comment: Can you share the code that resulted in this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.